# A property of Non-Injective, Continuous-function defined on a Compact-subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, banach-spaces

**Given $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $A=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \leq 2\}$. We have $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that f is continuous with the property $f(1,1)=f(-1,-1)$.
We have to prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x$ and $y$ in $A$
with $||x-y|| < \epsilon$ and $x\neq y$ such that f(x)=f(y).**

**My Thought:**
Since A is compact, f will attain its global maxima(M) and global minima(m).
If this can be shown that at least one of $f^{-1}(M)$ or $f^{-1}(m)$ is an interior point of $A$ by using the fact that $f$ is not injective.

(**Edit:** It is true that at least one of $f^{-1}(M)$ or $f^{-1}(m)$ is an interior point of $A$.
A proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850406/property-of-injective-continuous-function-on-compact-set/3850423#3850423).)

Then using that interior point as a pivot, we can catch hold of two distinct points in the $\epsilon/2$ nbd. of the pivot having the same functional value, using the continuity off f and the fact that f is not injective.

The motive behind this line of thinking is by considering a function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{2}-x ;  0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
        x- \frac{1}{2} ; \frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 1
       \end{cases}$$
In this function global minima is attained at $\frac{1}{2}$, which is an interior point. So for any $\epsilon > 0$ choose $\epsilon/2$ nbd. of $\frac{1}{2}$. There exists $x$ and $y$ in that nbd. such that $|x-y|<\epsilon$ and $x\neq y$ and f(x)=f(y).

**Edit:** *Generalization*- **Given $A \subset X$, where $X$ is a Banach-Space and $A$ is compact in $X$. If $f$ is a continuous-function from $A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and there exists $a,b \in A$ ($a\neq b$) with $f(a)=f(b)$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x,y \in A$
with ($||x-y|| < \epsilon$ and $x\neq y$) such that f(x)=f(y).**

Comment: What about taking *any* element $x\in A$ and then taking $y=x$? That will work.

Comment: Sorry I meant $x\neq y$

Comment: If that's what you mean, why don't you edit the question then?

Comment: Yes Sir. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=f(1,1)=f(-1,-1)$ and consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi\colon&[-1,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&t&\mapsto&f(t,t).\end{array}$$Then $\varphi$ is continuous and $\varphi(1)=\varphi(-1)=a$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous and $[-1,1]$ is an interval of $\Bbb R$ which is both closed and bounded, $\varphi$ has both a maximum $M$ and a minimum $m$.

If $M=m$, then $\varphi$ is constant and the problem is trivial: for any $\varepsilon>0$, just take any two distinct numbers $t_0,t_1\in[-1,1]$ such that $|t_0-t_1|<\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt2}$ and take $x=(t_0,t_0)$ and $y=(t_1,t_1)$. Then $x\ne y$, $\|x-y\|<\varepsilon$ and $f(x)=f(y)$.

If $M\ne m$, then $M>a$ or $a>m$. I will assume that $M>a$; the other case is similar. There is some $t\in(-1,1)$ such that $\varphi(t)=M$. There are two possibilities now:

1. There are numbers $t^*\in[-1,1]$ as close to $t$ as you want (but distinct from $t$)such that $\varphi(t^*)=M$. Then, given $\varepsilon>0$, you take one such $t^*$ such that $|t-t^*|<\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt2}$ and then you take $x=(t,t)$ and $y=(t^*,t^*)$; then $\|x-y\|<\varepsilon$, $x\ne y$, and $f(x)=f(y)$.
2. Near $t$, there is no element of $t^*\in[-1,1]$ such that $\varphi(t^*)=M$. Take $t_1>t$ such that $\varphi(t_1)<M$ and that $|t-t_1|<\frac\varepsilon{2\sqrt2}$ and take $t_2<t$ such that $\varphi(t_2)<M$ and that $|t-t_2|<\frac\varepsilon{2\sqrt2}$. If $\varphi(t_1)=\varphi(t_2)$, you're done; just take $x=(t_1,t_1)$ and $y=(t_2,t_2)$. If $\varphi(t_2)>\varphi(t_1)$, then, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is some $t_3\in(t,t_1)$ such that $\varphi(t_3)=\varphi(t_2)$; so, take $x=(t_1,t_1)$ and $y=(t_3,t_3)$. The case in which $\varphi(t_2)<\varphi(t_1)$ is similar.