# Property of Injective-Continuous-function on Compact-set.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ where A is compact and $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

If f is injective then the points in $A$ at which $f$ attains global maxima and minima are boundary points of $A$.  Is the statement true?
The motive for this question comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850166/a-property-of-non-injective-continuous-function-defined-on-a-compact-subset-of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly your statement is true if $n=1$ and $A$ is a compact interval. An injective continuous function on $A$ is either increasing or decreasing, and the global maxima and minima are on either endpoint of the interval.

Assume $f$ takes its global maximum at $x_0\in A$ and that $x_0$ is an interior point of $A$. Then consider a line segment
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=x_0+te_1$$
where $e_1=(1, 0, 0,...,0)$. For small enough $t$, we have $\mathbf{r}(t)\in A$ so the function $g(t)=f(\mathbf{r}(t))$ is well defined in a small compact interval $[-\delta,\delta]$ containing $t=0$. It is injective since $f$ is injective, and continuous as well.

According to our argument when $n=1$ it follows that $g$ takes its maximum on the boundary of $[-\delta,\delta]$ contradicting the fact that $g(0)=f(\mathbf{r}(0))=f(x_0)$ is the global maximum of $f$.

The argument is identical for a global minimum by reversing the sign of $f$.

Comment: I think this same argument can also be used for any Normed-Real-Vector-space. So this statement is also valid on compact subsets of a Normed-Real-Vector-space, right?

Comment: I'd think so, yes. Replace $e_1$ by any fixed non-zero vector.